# Access PostgreSQL database in Matlab without installing PostgreSQL

Tags: matlab, postgresql

I'm currently working with a PostgreSQL database using Matlab. I was wondering if an installation of PostgreSQL is necessarily required to let Matlab access the database or if it sufficed to only have Matlab installed and the corresponding database file saved on one's computer... ?

Does anyone know a solution that doesn't require a PostgreSQL installation?

Thanks!

Comment: If the data is not that big, perhaps you can move it from Postgres to SQLite. The latter _does_ allow access to the database via a simple library. For Postgres it seems unlikely for you to be able to read the files without having Postgres in between. Don't know for certain, so I'm just leaving a comment here.

Comment: Currently the backup file for the database has a size of 1.2 GB, but quite likely it will get a lot larger (up to 100 GB). Do you think SQLite can still cope with that?

Comment: I think it _might_ work. The [appropriate uses for sqlite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html) suggests it can handle bigger amounts of data and a lot of accesses to it. Since you're using it from matlab, I imagine the usage is more like - read everything from the database and do some data analysis on it, write something back to it. Which seems to be a indicated use-case.

Comment: And matlab seems to come with builtin sqlite support via [sqlite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/sqlite-object.html;jsessionid=82bf8bec3d2a1b741d5fc485f0b0)

Comment: You need to install the java JDBC driver from the pgsql website, also you need the database toolbox. Check [this](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/postgresql-jdbc-windows.html)